# Opensource stat server?

Tags: sql, statistics, nosql, redis

I've been looking for an opensource stat server that supports the following requirements:

- Local proxy to aggregate 100s stats per second, and sends those stats out to a central cluster (or single server) every 10 seconds or so.   The application will be making blocking network calls to the proxy to stat within the code rather than writing out to disk and having another process come and read the logs.
- The central server responds to queries that asks for aggregates in REALTIME (sub-second response) (stats per 5 minute interval, hour, day, month, year).  Optional: Support rolling time windows (e.g. 1 hour back from now)
- Tagging per stat metric.  Each stat name will have different attributes such as the hostname this stat is coming from.
- Monotonically increasing stats (stats that increase forever, i.e. total count)

I understand it is fairly straightforward to write your own (Table per day, aggregate lower granularity tables based on policy, then drop them per TTL, can be done on NOSQL, e.g. hashsets on redis keyed on time bucket), but am surprised that there isn't one readily available given that it is a standard use-case.  OpenTSDB is a close candidate (doesn't provide the local proxy) but doesn't support monotonically increasing stats.

Any suggestions or pointers?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at statsd, it's a really cool project that does more or less what you want. your app fires up UDP packets to a central node (you state a sample percentage you want to actually send to avoid overloading, we use about 10%), and the central server aggregates the data, which is labeled. It then uses Graphite to generate the actualy reports.

https://github.com/etsy/statsd